# KISS my... unit of work

Tags: c#, design-patterns, entity-framework, repository

I've seen many, many UoW+Repository implementations. Whenever one was built on top of Entity Framework, I'd cringe at the added complexity.

Sure the complexity buys you (sometimes) full decoupling from Entity Framework, which *in theory* would *possibly* allow swapping EF for, say, NHibernate, or even "downgrade" to a lower-level ADO.NET solution.

But most people implement an `IUnitOfWork` interface for the sole purpose of enabling easier testability - I'm one of those. I'm not buying the "*dude I can swap my ORM without touching the rest of my app*" argument, simply because it's more often than not, a theoretical advantage, if not a plain lie.

So I like to *keep it stupid simple* (KISS), and only do the minimum needed to enable mocking of my `DbContext` class - here's a real-world `IUnitOfWork` interface I've written in a recent project:

> **IUnitOfWork** interface

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    int SaveChanges();
    IDbSet<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
}
```

Entity Framework's `DbContext` **is** a unit of work, and `IDbSet<TEntity>` **is** a repository. So instead of going all out and writing a generic repository and adding a considerable amount of useless complexity (useless in the sense that *I don't need that to enable mocking my DbContext*), I'm making my `DbContext`-derived class implement my `IUnitOfWork` interface:

> **CallAssistantContext** class

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class CallAssistantContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public CallAssistantContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    { }

    public IDbSet<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public IDbSet<CustomerServiceCall> CustomerServiceCalls { get; set; }

    public IDbSet<CallType> CallTypes { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<ContactType> ContactTypes { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<IssueType> IssueTypes { get; set; }

    public IDbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<CustomerStore> CustomerStores { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<SalesRep> SalesReps { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

---

The "client code" depends on an abstraction - the `IUnitOfWork` interface, and can very easily be constructor-injected with a mock implementation in unit tests:

> ```
> public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
> {
>     private readonly IUnitOfWork _context;
>
>     public MainWindowViewModel(IUnitOfWork context)
>     {
>         _context = context;
>     }
> ```

Querying the context doesn't look too complicated either:

> ```
> var cutoffDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(7));
> ServiceCalls = _context.Repository<CustomerServiceCall>()
>                         .Where(e => e.CallStart >= cutoffDate)
>                         .ToList();
> ```

---

So, is anything blatantly wrong with this approach? Here I've injected the UoW/context directly where it's needed - in a bigger project I would have created a "service" and constructor-injected the UoW there instead.

Comment: Nice Title !!!!!

Comment: I have an example at https://github.com/imranbaloch/ASPNETIdentityWithOnion

Comment: The problem with trying to mock the IUnitOfWork interface is that you've promised the world. You've said that the MainWindowViewModel can do any query on any repository. Mocking that could be a significant amount of work. You might be better off creating an interface that only exposes methods you're actually going to use.. e.g. GetCustomerServiceCallsForCutOffDate(DateTime cutOffDate)

Comment: @craftworkgames good point - and I *would* have such a method in the "service" class I mentioned. And that service would have a dependency on `IUnitOfWork`, which would have to be mocked-up anyway - and that is the problem being solved here ;)

Comment: Yes, at some point you will obviously have to take a dependency on EF but the idea is to keep the amount of unmockable code to a minimum. This usually happens at the boundaries of the system, e.g. database, file system, UI, system clock, random.

Comment: It really depends on the scope of your application. I think the trick is to try writing the unit tests first. It will become painfully obvious fairly quickly as you build up the code if it's not going to work. At that point you can refactor.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Before posting an answer I want to know, is there a reason why you override `OnModelCreating` to call `base.OnModelCreating`?

Comment: Not really.. I usually go *code-first*, this project was *database-first*. The override is indeed superfluous.

Comment: There, worst.answer.ever. But I have nothing else to say

Comment: `simply because it's more often than not, a theoretical advantage, if not a plain lie.`
Tangent ahead: Whilst I agree with this, I recently had the struggle of having to go from EntityFramework to pure SQL. It was painful. That said, .edmx files make me cry and are infinitely more painful. Either way, an app should be written in a way such that you should be able to swap out ORM easily anyway - `IUnitOfWork` needn't be a factor :-)

Comment: @DanPantry interesting. This project started off MySQL, and I'm migrating everything to SQL Server - for me it's just a different provider, the ORM remains the same. I struggle to see *why* the ORM would ever need to be swapped, but happy to see a real-world case where it actually happened... my sympathies!

Comment: @DanPantry Bummer indeed. Perhaps I've been lucky, but I've never needed to swap out the data access layer in over twenty years on projects big and small. Change the database itself, sure, but never the ORM.

Comment: Regarding the Repository pattern, I wanted to provide a full-fledged alternate answer, but sadly enough i didn't have enough time - yet. However in the meantime i think @Steven's comment [here](http://crosscuttingconcerns.com/AOP-vs-decorator) is quite interesting in that regard.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd second TopinFrassi's answer, that this is a more or less sensible approach, and the implementation is excellent. However, there are some potential issues, which I'll expand from craftworkgames' comments and your response. Because I can't really find anything that needs criticism in how it's written, this will be entirely design focussed.

There are two central issue in passing an interface that claims it can provide

```
IDbSet<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
```

- You're promising *an awful lot*
- You're exposing this outside of directly data-access related code (even if it's in service classes, these classes are unlikely to all be directly DA related except perhaps in a very small application)

And the problems this can cause are:

1. Exposing much more than a consumer needs. Any class that only needs to deal with `SalesRep`s shouldn't also be passed a way to perform arbritrary crud operations on `Customer`s. This is a violation of the Interface Segregation Principle.
2. Difficulty of mocking. An interface that can provide a lot means a lot to mock. It's likely that you'll be able to narrow down what actually needs to get mocked in individual tests, but often the practicality of that is having to couple to implementation details of the SUT which you aren't really trying to test, which makes your tests more brittle.
3. A leaky abstraction. Abstractions are about more than just being able to swap implementations, which means even if you have no interest in doing that, a leaky abstraction is still a problem. In this case you're exposing the big EF gotcha to every class who ever has to deal with entities: `IQueryable`. It does a good impression of `IEnumerable`, but then throws exceptions for a lot of arguments to its LINQ extensions which `IEnumerable` would happily process. Having to remember that code will need to be converted into SQL is not an issue you should expose throughout your service layer.
4. A lack of entity-specific methods. In addition to giving all your service classes *too many general* methods, you may also be giving them *not enough specific* methods. It's quite likely that you'll have queries or commands for a particular entity type which you'll want to do in several places- including across several service classes- but which are long/complex enough that repeating the entire query or command would be a DRY violation.

### Resolving

That last problem is the one that screams out most for a particular answer, so let's start out with that. Say we've written a service class with a private method that does a complex query for us. Now we're writing another service class, and though the functionality isn't that similar, we find ourrselves needing the same query that was in that private method.

We do the obvious thing and pull the query out into its own class:

```
public class FirstFooService()
{
    public FirstFooService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, FooQueryHelper queryHelper) { //... }

    //...
}

public class SecondFooService()
{
    public SecondFooService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, FooQueryHelper queryHelper) { //... }

    //...
}
```

But now this really seems like a mess. We're relying on two different things- the unit of work and the query helper- to do our data access, at two different levels of abstraction. Which level do we actually want?

Well, I think the answer is straightforward. We added `FooQueryHelper` specifically because we found ourselves wanting that abstraction over accessing the `IUnitOfWork` directly. Moreover, if we look at the problems above, `FooQueryHelper` can solve all four of them. It solves 1,2 and 4 by its nature, and it can simply solve 3 by keeping its return types as `IEnumerable` rather than `IQueryable`, and by not exposing any methods which take an arbitrary `Func` or `Expression` to use as a filter.

All that remains is to extract the `IUnitOfWork` methods that we consume onto `FooQueryHelper`, narrowing them and making them more specific to keep them at the right abstraction level when possible. You can probably see the punchline coming- what we actually end up with isn't `FooQueryHelper`, but `FooRepository`. This can follow the standard generic repository pattern you'll find described all over the place. If you look back at the root problems, you can see these are solved too: now everything relies on a much smaller, more targeted interface, and data access concerns are kept in data access classes, rather than spreading out to every service that cares about entities.

### Conclusion

But what about KISS? Possibly you were already aware of the generic repository, and you wanted to avoid it because of its apparently needless complexity and indirection. Well, yes, as always there's the tradeoff- in a small, simple application, at what point does further SOLIDifying your code consume more development resources than it'll ever buy you back? That's a judgement call you'll have to make. But hopefully I've given some reasons beyond just "So I can swap my ORM" for why you might pick this more complex pattern.

Also note that the generic repository is, at its core, not actually all that complex or bulky to implement. It really starts out as just a thin wrapper over `IDbContext`. But don't be misled! A repository should **not** just be an adapter from `IDbSet` to an interface you control, it should be a full-blown abstraction layer! So if you do find yourself adding more methods, that's probably vindicating the choice of that pattern.

Comment: This specific application is very small, but this answer is beyond awesome, and very useful and highly valuable.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Glad to hear it, thanks very much for the feedback!

Comment: The FooQueryHelper would contain the querying logic for the UoW is that it? Is the helper specific to the implementation of the UoW, since it requires the `IQueryable<T>` interface? Or.. does it?

Comment: @TopinFrassi Right. The helper would use `IQueryable` but would not return it, so the implementation is specific to EF, but the interface it exposes is not. In case it wasn't clear from the answer, FooQueryHelper was an intermediary stage in showing how refactoring could bring you to a (generic) repository pattern.

Comment: That is what I thought, but I wanted to make sure I understood correctly :)

Comment: I was thinking about waiting for the end of the bounty to award it, but your answer made me think so much I decided I had to give it to you, thanks for the time you put in this answer, it is very valuable

Comment: @TopinFrassi Thanks very much for the feedback and the bounty!

Comment: So I'm just wondering, once you've got 30 queries related to `Foo`, a `FooRepository` class with 30 query methods is not really SOLID anymore (in regards to SRP and ISP). So how do you go from there? Well you could make the repository a Facade (not so cool in many regards, too) or you could extract the queries. But then you're arriving at exactly the `FirstFooService` and `SecondFooService` you describe: both depending on the `IUnitOfWork` (or `FooRepository` without query functionality) and the query types.

Comment: Taking things a step further, the same issue may arrise with `FirstFooService` and `SecondFooService`: When they begin to depend on many types it may not only point to bad abstraction, it may also point to the service not adhering to SOLID. But that's always the case for a Facade.
So what about something along the lines of Commands and Queries instead of services and repositories?

Comment: Also, come to think of it, how are `IUnitOfWork` and `FooQueryHelper` on two different levels of abstraction? If the only thing you do is merge them into `FooRepository`, how does that not make it two levels of abstraction? Or did i missunderstand that phrase " We're relying on two different things- the unit of work and the query helper- to do our data access, at two different levels of abstraction." ?

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit RE: 30 queries- true. At this point you'd possibly want to split your repository into several smaller ones if you can group queries by functionality. The commands and queries pattern is one I've never had time to get familiar with, but may in many cases be preferable to repositories. I'm not trying to sell the repository pattern, just explain the reasoning behind it since it's often communicated so confusingly.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I'm not sure what's not clear about the two levels of abstraction. `queryHelper.GetPendingMessages(string username, DateTime? since)` is a different level of abstraction from `querySet.Where(notice => notice.AssignedTo.Username == username).Where(notice => notice.Status == NoticeStatus.Pending).Where(notice => !since.HasValue || notice.RaisedAt >= since).Select(notice => notice.MessageBody)` for example. Especially keeping in mind that the latter is dealing with `IQueryable`, whereas the former can return `IEnumerable`.

Comment: regarding queries and commands: i think that when you do queries and commands, what they will use / based upon will be the `DbContext`. Adding an interface `IUnitOfWork` (or watchmacallit) for unit-testability is a matter of taste. So what i want to say is that commands & queries is an alternative to the "repository pattern" which does not necessarily need `FooServiceOne` to deal with two levels of abstraction.

Comment: regarding the "two levels of abstraction": I agree, your example is on two levels of abstraction. But i still don't get how `FirstFooService` is using two levels of abstraction, would the `IQueryable` stuff not be part of the implementation of the `FooQueryHelper` (and thus be invisible to `FirstFooService`)? Maybe I'm misunderstanding things, i don't know...

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit At the stage where it's getting the two level of abstraction, it would have `FooQueryHelper`, which would expose methods like the `GetPendingMessages` above. For those there's no good reason to expose `IQueryable`, so they'd return `IEnumerable`. But then for queries/commands without helpers, they'd use the `IDbSet` from the `IUnitOfWork`/`DbContext`. And calls on the `IDbSet` would look like the second example snippet there, the `querySet.Where(...`. So a class that takes a `FooQueryHelper` and `IUnitOfWork` dependency would be working at those two different levels.

Answer (score 4):

Your code seems really good to me, I don't have anything else to say but that I'd remove the `OnModelCreating` override, as it has no purposes.